# Why can't start pgbouncer process when setting logfile to /var/log/ path?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

This pgbouncer.ini setting can't start pgbouncer:

```
[databases]
mydb = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 6432
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
auth_type = md5
auth_file = userlist.txt
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = someuser
```

No pid file generated, no log file created. No process running(`ps aux | grep pgbouncer`).

But if set `logfile` and `pidfile` to:

```
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
```

pgbouncer can be started by run `pgbouncer -d pgbouncer.ini`. It will create log file and pid file at the same path of `pgbouncer.ini`.

I am using normal user doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you don't have permission to write to `/var/log/pgbouncer` as the user you are running as, or the directory doesn't exist and pgbouncer doesn't or can't create it.

A third possibility is that the permissions on that directory are TOO relaxed, but I don't think pgbouncer checks that.

Comment: Thank you. I have to install PostgreSQL server and do it by `postgres` user.